# How to consume WSDL provided by Active Directory Certificate Services (CEP server)?

Tags: active-directory, wsdl, certificate, x509certificate, client-certificates

Is there documentation about how to consume WSDL provided by AD CS. A tutorial or code samples for this? This web service is provided by AD CS but there seems to be no guidance about how to use it.

I know that there are [IX509Enrollment2](https://nam06.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fwindows%2Fdesktop%2Fapi%2Fcertenroll%2Fnn-certenroll-ix509enrollment2&data=02%7C01%7CNedim.Sahin%40microsoft.com%7C824af8195b624acb5aa908d6fbe34f00%7C72f988bf86f141af91ab2d7cd011db47%7C1%7C0%7C636973351056495687&sdata=N1RXuN8BUd4Eq0N0LyLEmosVnmSf%2Fc%2B7puVMrXOnOkk%3D&reserved=0) and [ICertRequest](https://nam06.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fwindows%2Fdesktop%2Fapi%2Fcertcli%2Fnn-certcli-icertrequest&data=02%7C01%7CNedim.Sahin%40microsoft.com%7C824af8195b624acb5aa908d6fbe34f00%7C72f988bf86f141af91ab2d7cd011db47%7C1%7C0%7C636973351056505687&sdata=VELNs%2BVkOywkAlz96DuRgt6PO23mgG6O43Ic9b%2Bl3uM%3D&reserved=0) interfaces to perform certificate operations but I am wondering if we can use the web service via WSDL file.

Sample WSDL:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Although, no code samples, but there are complete protocol specifications:

- [[MS-XCEP]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-xcep/08ec4475-32c2-457d-8c27-5a176660a210) -- this protocol is used to load policies, certificate templates and enrollment services with [MS-WSTEP] support.
- [[MS-WSTEP]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-wstep/4766a85d-0d18-4fa1-a51f-e5cb98b752ea) -- this protocol is used to perform certificate enrollment, request submission, issued certificate retrieval.

in appendixes you will find sample messages.